# Reuse and concat my Login Scenario to other Scenarios in Cucumber Java with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, gherkin

I am trying to test Amazon website with 3 scenarios. When first login scenario is done. When trying to other scenarios, it goes to the initial condition and do not logged in when trying to add products in the cart. Basically, I want to login first and concat this functionality to other scenarios or features in Cucumber Selenium.

The below gherkin language is my Amazon.feature;

```
Feature: Being able to shop through the website in e-commerce platform, Amazon.



Scenario: Login to the system

Given User is on homepage

When Click accept cookies

When User click login button

When User click EmailBlank

And Enter e-mail address

And User press continue button

When User click PasswordBlank

And Enter password

And Click SignIn button




Scenario: Find the product from the website

When Click the search button

When Write product name

When Click search button

When Filter for Shipped by Amazon

When Filter for Apple




Scenario: Adding and deleting product to cart

When Click the first product

When Add to Cart

And Close the Cart

And Click the Cart

When Check at cart page

When Delete the product
```

Most probably I should use background keyword, but can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In case all these scenarios you have in one feature file, then it is ok if you logged into the system in the first scenario and just execute other scenarios without relogging.

But you **logged out** from the app in the first Scenario: And Click SignIn button. Therefore the next scenario fails.

2 options here (or 1st, or 2nd):

1. do not log out in the first scenario (remove And Click SignIn button.)
2. make a Background for login like

   Background:
   @Given User is on homepage

But in this second case with the background you must log out in the end of each your scenario.

Hope it helps.

UPD based on the comment:

```
Feature: Being able to shop through the website in e-commerce platform, Amazon.

Background
Given User is on homepage (I am assuming this step is for login)
When Click accept cookies
When User click login button
When User click EmailBlank
And Enter e-mail address
And User press continue button
When User click PasswordBlank
And Enter password
And Click SignIn button

Scenario: Find the product from the websitep
When Click the search button
When Write product name
When Click search button
When Filter for Shipped by Amazon
When Filter for Apple
**Then LOG OUT**


Scenario: Adding and deleting product to cart

When Click the first product
When Add to Cart
And Close the Cart
And Click the Cart
When Check at cart page
When Delete the product
**Then LOG OUT**
```

Comment: I do not log out in any of the scenarios, I put Scenario for login it works. But in this case, my scenario number decreased from 3 to 2. I want to test login functionality first and close the terminal and then for the second test to be able to search products, make website logged in first. But this time test behaves like 2 scenarios.

Comment: I am sorry, I have read 'And Click SignIn button' incorrect. I see. So if now I understood you right, n case if you need, 1st scenario to check log in, then you may try to add common Background for login step only, remove log in step from the first scenario, in the end of all scenarios you add log out steps, and the second and other scenarios should not have log in steps as well as the 1st scenario, because log in Background will be executed before each scenario.

Comment: corrected my answer how I see then your feature file, fyi